# How to sort & "crop" a dictionary list in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, extension-methods

I wanna use only top N list items and delete the rest. I thought I duplicated & sorted **matches** as **_listTopN** but when I clear **matches** it also clears **_listTopN**

In short, how can I get the max 3 list items in an unordered dictionary list and put them back that same dictionary?

```
Dictionary<int, float> matches;
```

...

```
if (matches.Count > Settings.requiredMatch)
{
   var _listTopN = matches.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value).Take(Settings.requiredMatch);

   matches.Clear();

   foreach (var p in _listTopN)
      matches.Add(p.Key, p.Value);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq queries are evaluated lazily. Your statement where you assign `_listTopN` doesn't perform any work, it only prepares the query ; this query will only be executed when you start enumerating the results. Since you clear `matches` before you start enumerating the query, there is nothing in the source to enumerate...

If you want the query to be evaluated eagerly, add `ToList` at the end:

```
var _listTopN = matches.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value)
                       .Take(Settings.requiredMatch)
                       .ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can use `ToDictionary` to perform all the work in a single query:

```
matches = matches.OrderBy(s => s.Value)
                 .Take(Settings.requiredMatch)
                 .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Force it to evaluate earlier:

```
var _listTopN = matches.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value)
    .Take(Settings.requiredMatch).ToList();
```

LINQ has deferred execution (as part of composition); in most cases, nothing is actually *evaluated* until you `foreach` over the data. The `ToList()` makes this happen earlier, i.e. before you clear the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the result to `matches` with `ToDictionary`:

```
if (matches.Count > Settings.requiredMatch)
{
    matches = matches
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.Value)
        .Take(Settings.requiredMatch)
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `_listTopN` is holding on to a deferred query, lazily executed when you loop on it.

In other words, `var _listTopN = ...` does not evaluate the query, it returns a recipe for how to evaluate it when needed.

Since you clear the underlying source before you evaluate it, it'll "change", that is, return something other than what you wanted/expected.

The simple fix is to force evaluation, so do this:

```
var _listTopN = matches.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value)
    .Take(Settings.requiredMatch).ToArray();
                                 ^--------^  <-- add this
```

This evaluates your query and stores the result as an array that won't change, and now you can safely clear your underlying data source.

Answer (score 2):

Your LINQ expression `_listTopN` is lazily evaluated which means that it doesn't evaluate its result until your `foreach` statement. But at this point you have already cleared `matches` source, so you get nothing in `_listTopN` also. You can force LINQ methods to evaluate their results by calling `ToArray` for example.

```
 var _listTopN = matches.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value).Take(Settings.requiredMatch)
                          .ToArray();
```

See this statement in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution

Answer (score 1):

```
if (matches.Count > Settings.requiredMatch)
  matches = matches.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value)
  .Take(Settings.requiredMatch)
  .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
```

Gets `matches` into the state you want simply and clearly.